# Soma e Subtração de valores com checkbox e select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, angularjs

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda? Estou precisando fazer uma soma e subtração de checkbox e select com valores e mostrar o resultado conforme for sendo selecionado os campos, alguém poderia me dar um caminho para seguir?

Comment: Não dá pra entender o que você quer. Tem como tentar ser mais claro e dar um exemplo do que você pretende fazer? Você pode [edit] a sua pergunta a qualquer momento.

Comment: O caminho a seguir, primeiramente, ler esses posts 1 - https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/ 2 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Coloque na pergunta pelo menos o HTML com os checkbox e select

Comment: Falta o código para gente analisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo simples, já que você não deixou muito claro o que precisa.

```
<select id="opcao_soma_val1" name="soma">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
<select>

<input  id="opcao_soma_val2" value="1" type="number" step="1" min="1" max="10">
<div id="resultado"><!-- aqui vem o resultado --></div>
<button id="somar">Somar</button>
<button id="subtrair">Subtrair</button>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>

$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#somar', function(){
     somar();
  });
 $(document).on('click','#subtrair', function(){
     subtrair();
  });

});
function subtrair(){
     var val1 = $('#opcao_soma_val1').val();
     var val2 = $('#opcao_soma_val2').val();
     var result = (parseInt(val1) - parseInt(val2));
     $('#resultado').text(result);
  } 
function somar(){
     var val1 = $('#opcao_soma_val1').val();
     var val2 = $('#opcao_soma_val2').val();
     var result = (parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2));
     $('#resultado').text(result);
  } 
</script>
```

> Para somar em tempo real, basta fazer blur no último campo.

Exemplo:

```
$('#opcao_soma_val2').on('blur', function(){
  somar();
});
```

[**Fiddle do exemplo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mpppkaLr/)

Comment: Seria isso mesmo, existe a possibilidade do resultado ser apresentado sem clicar no botão? O resultado ser apresentado em “tempo real”, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sim claro, olha aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/nq9Lts0f/